# CSS linear gradient not scrolling with content

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

### Problem

I have a textarea which uses a linear gradient as its background image. I am trying to emulate a "lined paper" effect. I've set my `font-size` and `line-height` to the get the correct spacing between the lines and the text;

[image: Lined paper textarea with correct margins]

however, once I scroll down the textarea, I notice a problem:

[image: Lined paper textarea with messed up text and lines]

Namely, that my background-image does not scroll with the text. I have tried `background-attachment: scroll`, `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-attachment: local`, and none solve my problem.

### CSS

```
textarea {
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
                                                #fff,
                                                #fff 9.5%,
                                                #000 9.5%,
                                                #000 10%);
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacksonrayhamilton/95mG3/)

Comment: background-attachment: local is the only solution you have. It's not widely supported though...

Answer (score 1):

`background-attachment: local` actually *does* work; just not in Firefox, where I was testing.